# Remove subview view controllers inside scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` (paging is enabled) with 4 `UIViewControllers` in it. I noticed that everytime I navigate/scroll to those view controllers the memory increases gradually. I have an idea that I must remove the subview `UIViewControllers` inside the `UIScrollView` if the controller is not displayed, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone share their ideas on how to remove unused `UIViewControllers` and put them back again in the `UIScrollView`.

This is my code on adding subviews in the scrollview.

```
controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
first.view.tag = 0;
[scrollView addSubview:first.view];
first.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 768, 919) ;
[controllers addObject:first];

second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
second.view.tag = 1;
[scrollView addSubview:second.view];
second.view.frame = CGRectMake(768 , 0, 768, 919) ;
[controllers addObject:second];

third = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];
third.view.tag = 2;
[scrollView addSubview:third.view];
third.view.frame = CGRectMake(768 + 768, 0, 768, 919) ;
[controllers addObject:third];

fourth = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Fourth"];
fourth.view.tag = 3;
[scrollView addSubview:fourth.view];
fourth.view.frame = CGRectMake(768 + 768 + 768, 0, 768, 919) ;
[controllers addObject:fourth];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a bunch of `UIViewController`s as opposed to using `UIView`s?

Comment: @AdamPro13 makes a good point. Assuming that you can't change your current design though, you should check if your view controllers (or some properties/iVars within) are getting allocated every time the scroll view pans over them.